# Blender merge textures into single file

Tags: texturing

Theres lots of stuff on internet about baking etc. but its so complicated and blender keep changing position of stuff in every update and im not downgrading in any way. Wheres method to merge the textures? I need merge 5 textures i dont need to specific im not talking about shaders
just theres a object uses 5 textures am i right? some of texture coordinates use these textures i just need make them merged into one file and keep the uvs
model is single everything is joined.

I need this beacuse game engine im using dont support mtl files or multiple textures i need merge all of them into single file and there is no way to change the engine.

Sidenote: I meant 5 textures being merged on one file and texture coordinates use them i just hate people keep saying what you asking for even though i tell the details.

[image] Example of texture type i need not cc by sa copyrighted

Comment: Hello, could you post an example of texture accepted by your game engine for comparison ?

Comment: So you want an Atlas Texture ? That's pretty common, what part do you have trouble with ? Do you know how to UV unwrap your models ?